# Error in loading shared libraries

Tags: linux, pcre

I am working on arch linux. To create an archiso,  i needed libpcre.so.0. for that i installed pcre using 
     pacman -S pcre.
Now when i restarted my system httpd i.e. my Apache server didn't start at boot time. So when i entered 
     rc.d restart httpd 
it gave me the following error.
     usr/sbin/httpd.worker: Error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.0 :Cannot open
     shared object file. No such file or directories.

Please can anyone tell me the solution to this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

goto "System -> Administration -> Synaptic Package Manager"

Install the packages "libpcrecpp0" and "libpcre++0"

It should work Easily then !!!